# How to correctly build a ring buffer in a kernel space program?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to write a program with a ring buffer in kernel space and it works fine on userspace, I replaced the memory allocators with kmalloc and get a type conversion error. Here is the program on userspace:

```
main ()
{
  char last_char = 'a';
  RingBuffer *buffer = newRingBuffer (10);
  RingBuffer_trywrite (buffer, last_char);
  RingBuffer_tryread(buffer, &last_char);
  printf ("%s", &last_char);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is part of the code from the kernel space program:

```
struct RingBuffer* buffer;
static int __init ch_drv_init(void) {
buffer = newRingBuffer(BUF_CAPACITY);
}
```

The implementation of the ring buffer is taken from wikipedia([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кольцевой_буфер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80))

[image]

Comment: Did you `typedef` your struct somewhere? Based on the error messages it looks like your function arguments are using a typedef and the kernel stuff is using the full struct name (including `struct` keyword). Using type names consistently might resolve the issue. The bigger concern is those warnings about implicit conversion from pointer to integer. Those warnings should be errors, really. Don't ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

#define CHAR_SIZE (sizeof(char))
#define RINGBUFFER_OK (0)
#define RINGBUFFER_ERR_NULL (-1)
#define RINGBUFFER_ERR_EMPTY (-2)
#define RINGBUFFER_ERR_FULL (-3)

struct RingBuffer {
    char *start;
    char *end;
    volatile char *readptr;
    volatile char *writeptr;
};

struct RingBuffer *newRingBuffer(unsigned long int capacity)
{
    struct RingBuffer *rb;
    char *mem = vmalloc(capacity * CHAR_SIZE);
    if (mem == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    rb = vmalloc(sizeof(*rb));
    if (rb == NULL) {
        vfree(mem);
        return NULL;
    }

    rb->start = mem;
    rb->end = mem + capacity;
    rb->readptr = mem;
    rb->writeptr = mem;

    return rb;
}

void deleteRingBuffer(struct RingBuffer *rb)
{
    if (rb == NULL)
        return;

    vfree(rb->start);
    vfree(rb);
}

int RingBuffer_trywrite(struct RingBuffer *rb, char c)
{
    volatile char *tmp;
    if (rb == NULL)
        return RINGBUFFER_ERR_NULL;

    if (rb->writeptr + 1 == rb->readptr)
        return RINGBUFFER_ERR_FULL;

    *(rb->writeptr) = c;
    tmp = rb->writeptr + 1;
    if (tmp >= rb->end) tmp = rb->start;
    rb->writeptr = tmp;

    return RINGBUFFER_OK;
}

int RingBuffer_tryread(struct RingBuffer *rb, char *c)
{
    volatile char *tmp;
    if (rb == NULL)
        return RINGBUFFER_ERR_NULL;

    if (rb->readptr == rb->writeptr)
        return RINGBUFFER_ERR_EMPTY;

    *c = (*rb->readptr);
    tmp = rb->readptr + 1;
    if (tmp >= rb->end) tmp = rb->start;
    rb->readptr = tmp;

    return RINGBUFFER_OK;
}

static int __init init_test_module(void)
{
    char last_char = 'a';
    struct RingBuffer *buffer = newRingBuffer(10);
    RingBuffer_trywrite(buffer, last_char);
    RingBuffer_tryread(buffer, &last_char);
    pr_info("last_char: %c\n", last_char);
    deleteRingBuffer(buffer);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_test_module(void)
{
}

module_init(init_test_module);
module_exit(exit_test_module);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: It wouldn't work properly on SMP.